# How to avoid "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." in MySql/net connector?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, mysql-connector

I have this following piece of code:

```
public TimestampedRowStorage GetTimestampedRowStorage(string startTime, string endTime, long trendSettingID, int? period)
    {
        var timestampedList = (from t in dataContext.TrendRecords
                                     where t.TrendSetting_ID == trendSettingID
                                     select t).ToList();

        return new TimestampedRowStorage
        {
            TimestampedDictionary = timestampedList.ToDictionary(m => m.Timestamp,
                m => (from j in dataContext.TrendSignalRecords
                      where j.TrendRecord_ID == m.ID
                      select j).ToDictionary(p => p.TrendSignalSetting.Name,
                p => (double?)p.Value))
        };
    }
```

But I always get the following exception:

> There is already an open DataReader
>   associated with this Connection which
>   must be closed first.

Here is the stack trace:

> [MySqlException (0x80004005): There is
>   already an open DataReader associated
>   with this Connection which must be
>   closed first.]
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
>   +237    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +146
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +47
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +10
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +443
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An
>   error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +479
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection
>   parameterValues) +736
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +149
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption
>   mergeOption) +31
>
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption
>   mergeOption) +148
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
>   +37    System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
>   +8032198    System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.get_Value()
>   +12    Nebula.Models.TrendSignalRecord.get_TrendSignalSetting()
>   in C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Models\SmgerDataModel.Designer.cs:2528
>   Nebula.Models.Trends.TrendRepository.<GetTimestampedRowStorage>b__b(TrendSignalRecord
>   p) in C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Models\Trends\TrendRepository.cs:229
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2
>   elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1
>   comparer) +226
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2
>   elementSelector) +54
>   Nebula.Models.Trends.TrendRepository.b__a(TrendRecord
>   m) in C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Models\Trends\TrendRepository.cs:227
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2
>   elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1
>   comparer) +240
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2
>   elementSelector) +53
>
>   Nebula.Models.Trends.TrendRepository.GetTimestampedRowStorage(String
>   startTime, String endTime, Int64
>   trendSettingID, Nullable`1 period) in
>   C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Models\Trends\TrendRepository.cs:224
>   Nebula.Models.Trends.TrendRepository.GetTrendSettingContainer(String
>   startTime, String endTime, Int64
>   unitID, Int64 plantID, Int64
>   trendSettingID, GridSortOptions
>   gridSortOptions, Nullable`1 page,
>   Nullable`1 recordsPerPage, Nullable`1
>   period, Int64[] trends, Nullable`1
>   allTrends) in C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Models\Trends\TrendRepository.cs:206
>   Nebula.Controllers.GeneratingUnitController.TrendSettings(Int64
>   id, Int64 plantID, Int64
>   trendSettingID, String startTime,
>   String endTime, Nullable`1 page,
>   Nullable`1 recordsPerPage,
>   GridSortOptions options, Nullable`1
>   period, Int64[] trends, Nullable`1
>   allTrends) in C:\Users\Bruno
>   Leonardo\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Nebula\Nebula\Controllers\GeneratingUnitController.cs:148
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase
>   , Object[] ) +543

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is probably because you are trying to access the database while you are accessing the database.
You should try to separate the two Linq expressions.
Maybe put something like this:

```
var TimestampedList = (from t in dataContext.TrendRecords
                                         where t.TrendSetting_ID == trendSettingID
                                         select t).ToList();
TimestampedDictionary = timestampedList.ToDictionary(m => m.Timestamp,
                    m => (from j in dataContext.TrendSignalRecords
                          where j.TrendRecord_ID == m.ID
                          select j).ToDictionary(p => p.TrendSignalSetting.Name,
                    p => (double?)p.Value))
```

Comment: Both Tejo and Ladislav Mrnka related to the use of ToList(), but it just changes the place of the exception (it now happens deeper in my code). I'll edit my question with a piece of the Stack Trace.

Comment: @Bruno what do you mean by deeper in the code?  That stack trace looks like it's the exact issue both answers addressed.  Maybe you have multiple instances of this issue in your code?  Is this the only place you use LINQ with the MySql connector?

Comment: @SRM It is not the only place, but I checked if it was working by, instead of create the second dictionary, instantiating a new one, and it worked. This means that if there is a problem somewhere, that is the place.

Comment: @SRM By deeper I meant "not in my code" ... it probably got lost in translation.

Comment: @Bruno Well without digging into the mysql connector code it's hard to tell what's going on.  There just might be a bug in the connector code.

Answer (score 13):

call .toList() in the first query

Answer (score 10):

I assume MySql connector doesn't support MARS (Multiple active result sets). In such case you cannot do this:

```
L2SQuery.ToDictionary(m => m.Timestamp, m => AnotherL2SQuery)
```

Once you do this you are enumerating result of the first L2S query (= `DataReader` is still open) and you are executing second L2S query for each record from the first one (= you need second `DataReader`).

You must execute first query separately by calling `ToList` and after that iterate result and build dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error today too. I was using a connection for more than one thing. Like this:

```
  MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(....);
  conn.Open();
  // Created a database here
  // Populdate the database there
  conn.Close();
```

But when I opened and closed the connection for each action, it worked:

```
  MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(....);
  conn.Open();
  // Created a database here
  conn.Close();
  conn.Open();
  // Populdate the database there
  conn.Close();
```